# PHP array variables being assigned values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fairly new to PHP and Codeigniter so im sure this will be simple.

I have contact details stored in this format where type is either (1,2,3,4) mapping to (facebook, mobile, bbm, msn, twitter):

```
ID | USERID | TYPE | VALUE
1  |    8   |  2   | 076773635
```

I have set up a model to access these contact details, there may be none, or at best one of each type;

```
function getContactDetails($userid) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM who_user_contact_info WHERE userid=".$userid);

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        switch ($row->type) {
            case 1:
                $contact['facebook'] = $row->value;  
            case 2:
                $contact['mobile'] = $row->value; 
            case 3:
                $contact['bbm'] = $row->value; 
            case 4:
                $contact['msn'] = $row->value;  
            case 5:
                $contact['twitter'] = $row->value; 
        }

    }


    return $contact;
}
```

My controller then passed this data to my view;

```
<h3>Contact Info</h2>
<?php   
    echo "Facebook: ". $facebook ."<br />";
    echo "mobile:".  $mobile ." <br />";
    echo "bbm:".  $bbm ." <br />";
    echo "msn:".  $msn ." <br />";
    echo "Twitter:".  $twitter ." <br />";
?>
```

This seems to nearly work, but there must be a mistake, as for example say type 3 and 5 didn't exist, mobile and twitter shouldn't have been assigned anything! yet on my output it gives the value from the one before, eg bbm=mobile and twitter=msn.

How is it possible for these array to be there when the case has not set them? or is my logic wrong?

Comment: While your answer is any of the `break;` answers, you can return from the `switch` (*and presumably remove the `foreach`*), as your code suggests `getContactDetails()` will only ever accept a single `$userid`. If **that** were the case, you wouldn't need the `break;` as each `case` would itself return from the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't you need to put a break under each case?

```
case 1:
$contact['facebook'] = $row->value;  
break;
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You need a `break;` in each case after setting the variable.